# How can I create a batch that searches all (unknown) shared folders on the local network for a specific folder?

Tags: search, batch-file, networking

We have several hundred clients with unique server names on their own local networks that hosts a specific folder called "Installs". Ultimately what I'm trying to put together is a batch that finds this folder with said name and use an MSI file in that folder to install on their machine. The server name could just be anything, the only thing I know for sure is that it will be sharing out that specific folder. I've tried many variations of net view, find, dir, wmic share.. no such luck, no abilities to search all available network resources. I was thinking I could do a net view > shared.txt and somehow use the names it has in there to search for "Installs" on these machines. I'm just at a loss though, it seems like I'd have to start parsing which is a bit above me. Would anyone have any idea how to do this?

Net view remarks...

```
Server Name            Remark

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 \\TDF-DESK2                                                           
 \\FWM-LAPT                                                            
 \\CAC-VCM                                                             
 \\BNE-DESK                                                            
 \\MAXBETA              Win2008R2 Std - Beta Test Server
```

Comment: Do you have all of the servers mapped to the machine that you will be running the script from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This searches each share available to your machine and searches for the `foldername` listed on line 2.

```
@echo off
set "folder=foldername"
for /f %%a in ('net view ^|find "\\"') do if not "%%a"=="\\%computername%" (
    echo trying server "%%a"
    pushd "%%a" && (
             for /d /r %%b in (%folder%*) do if /i "%%~nxb"=="%folder%" echo server "%%a" folder "%%b"
             popd
            )
)
pause
```

**Earlier answer below:**

Test this on a LAN - change the `foldername*` but leave the `*` there.
It should just echo the `path\folders` that match.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
net share |repl "^.*(.:\\.*)" "$1" a|repl "  *$" ""|repl "\\  *.*" "\"|repl "^..\\windows.*" "" i >temp.tmp
for /f "delims=" %%a in (temp.tmp) do (
for /d /r "%%a" %%b in (foldername*) do echo "%%b"
)
del temp.tmp
pause
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to give this a shot later today and will follow up.

Comment: Gave it a shot and it goes to pause relatively quick. Not sure if it's actually performing the commands. I did notice you used net share(which shows what the workstation your on is sharing) as opposed to net view. I tried altering it a bit and no such luck.

Comment: Did you download `repl.bat`?  It does check only the shares available to the machine. Tell me if you see any error messages. This would be run using `psexec` on each machine as I see it, because you can't install an executable over a LAN.

Comment: Yes I did. I have 4 servers on my work LAN here, all are sharing out folders. I tested it by plugging in a folder name on one of those servers.

Comment: I just tried your edit above, it seems to be working. Searching each available share for the keyword. Is there any way to suppress the "The network path was not found." reports where it's not found? This site is awesome, definitely getting a donation from me. Thanks again for your responses.

Comment: Ok I just keep getting a returning "The network path was not found". I have 6 servers, so I guess it doesn't know to stop after that 6. And it also didn't find the "Upgrades" folder that was \\Srb01\Upgrades

Comment: Can you add the output from the `net view` command to your question (in plain text, not image) so I can see what should be parsed?

Comment: This is one of our domains, anyway. I changed up some letters, just so this info isn't public. Thanks for your help with this, foxidrive.

Comment: Thanks, it is the format I expected and the code should work if you have permissions to access all the shares.  What error do you see on the console window? I added some error checking for servers without access permissions - it will not search the current drive if it fails to access the server - and I improved the accuracy of folder detection.  It should not have any false matches now.