# Batch Search for Folder in a network share and reveal full UNC to folder

Tags: batch-file, search, unc, drives

I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the following using batch files.

I need to establish a network path to a shared folder before I can ask a client to install software. Once I have the path I can configure the install package and ask them to deploy, all ready for when other elements of set up process completed.

In order to make it fool proof I was thinking I could instruct the customer to make a folder called e.g. "DataStore DO NOT MOVE" on any of their mapped drives\shares.

E.g. M:\ "or"  S:\ "or" N:\ etc. etc. (with various dir's accessible to all users on the site)

Usually they have at least 1 or more.

So they make the folder "M:\DataStore DO NOT MOVE" "or" "M:\shared_area\DataStore DO NOT MOVE" "or" "S:\DataStore DO NOT MOVE" "or" "S:\shared_area\DataStore DO NOT MOVE"

and then run this batch file that searches the shared folders \ mapped drives for the specific folder created and reports back the full UNC, so

> `folder found on "\\Server\data\shared_area\DataStore DO NOT MOVE"`

Hope that makes sense. And to be perfectly honest I don't know if this is possible as it's something I wouldn't know where to start with.

> I had a look at this article
>   [How can I create a batch that searches all (unknown) shared folders on the local network for a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869536/how-can-i-create-a-batch-that-searches-all-unknown-shared-folders-on-the-local)
>   but did not work for me.

Ultimately I would prefer not to have the client do anything. The best solution would be they run the batch (or what ever it may end up being) it then finds a writable share or mapped drive, creates a folder of a defined name, then sends me the full path in a text file to my drop box. This stage I can achieve using "curl". Tried and tested.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at your previous questions, you never recognized and upvoted any answer posted, but instead copied them as your own answers. Most of these were later deleted by mods due to errors you made. What motivation do you think people still have to help you?

Comment: Yes on previous question I got the format wrong, was a bad day. To say I haven't recognized any answers isn't entirely fair, I'am thankful within the comments section. Given the up voting is essential, I will update everything previous. I really value this site and don't want to offend anybody, that isn't the intention at all. Hopefully can move on in a manner more acceptable to the users of the site? #edit Although when I try and up vote it says it will be recorded but not visible. Maybe I need more points etc.?

Comment: It's working now. Also the passing off some ones answer as my own, it's clear as day it's not mine, I was copying the working text, as several came in at once, and pasting as a new answer to show people what worked, instead of commenting or voting properly my bad, but corrected use of the site, hopefully.

Comment: What didn't work for you in the above linked solution?

Comment: I made a folder share with a given name and ran the top code standalone then the bottom one with the helper repl.Bat. Neither found the folder.  Even made folder name as same in code so I didn't have to alter anything.  Thanks for reply.

Comment: Net View may not show all or any network PCs on a target network. This issue was broadly reported on the web, and depends on Windows version used.

Comment: I'll Park this one for now.  Thanks all the same.